# How to Set Up Universal Links to Deep Link on Apple iOS 9?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9, deep-linking

I have a `unsigned.json` file I want to convert it into `apple-app-site-association`. How can this be done?

```
openssl smime -sign -nodetach -in unsigned.json -out apple-app-site-association -outform DER -inkey output_key.pem -signer output_crt.pem
```

Apple says Universal Links
---> RECOMMENDED

```
The apple-app-site-association file was found but it doesn’t follow the required format.
```

Comment: I suggested first you upload your apple-app-site-association with no signed file and check if you have the same message. At least you can detect if your problem is for your Signed (certificate) or file format.

Comment: @Beto i uploaded my apple-app-site-association with no signed file not getting any issue Universal Links to be passed

Comment: Ok. Then you can leave this unsigned file for Universal Links. Apple does not required signed file... but if you insist signed file, please left the procedure in this website, because I can not do that neither :)

Comment: From the Universal Links documentation: "Universal links require hosting a SIGNED json file with designated applinks in it.". Other Q&A's here confirm that the json file needs to be signed with a valid certificate and private key for an identity issued by a certificate authority trusted by iOS.

Answer (score 3):

There are several steps involved in signing the file. Here's the command we use at my company for our partners' apps:

`cat apple-app-site-association-unsigned | openssl smime -sign -inkey yourdomain.com.key -signer yourdomain.com.cert -certfile digicertintermediate.cert -noattr -nodetach -outform DER > apple-app-site-association`

There are many possible mistakes that you can make along the way in generating the key, certs, etc., so I suggest following a guide. [Pulled from this blog post](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9). Also, at [Branch](https://branch.io) we've implemented all of the server-side logic required for Universal Links, so you can make use of Universal Links after making the required additions to your app entitlements (this is about 1/10th of the work).